# AWS API Gateway Invalid cache key parameter specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to change the body mapping template of get method integration request.
But the  Invalid cache key parameter specified showed. What happened ? I try to close the query mapping, reopen browser, relogin or remove the template to build a new one, However the Invalid cache key parameter specified error dialog still showed up.

Here is my template

```
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
    #end
#end
}
```

If there are something details you want to ask for to help me, please let me know.

Comment: Are you using the console to create the API? Or CloudFormation/Swagger Import? What parameters do you have on the 'Method Request' screen?

Comment: I solved this issue, since the aws support engineer told me that the testing console and api stage are different, so I changed to another template to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that the aws api gateway testing and stage deploy are in different way.
Here is the template that solved this problem.

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
#if ($input.params().querystring.keySet().contains("id"))
{
"id": $input.params().querystring.get('id')
}
#end
```